# Google map marker does not load first time around

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

My Google map Marker does not load first time (but it does centre on address) unless I add the following code to the bottom...

```
 marker.setPosition(latlng);
```

Why is this the case? This is the same in all browsers I have tested FF, IE and Chrome etc/

Thanks for any help.

```
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var marker;

    function initialize(){
    //MAP

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng('xxxxx','xxxxx');
      var options = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

      //GEOCODER
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



      markerImg = google.maps.MarkerImage({
        url: "newIcon.png"
      });

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: markerImg,
        draggable: true
      });



;

    }

    $(document).ready(function() { 

      initialize();

etc
```

Answer (score 5):

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: markerImg,
    draggable: true,
    position: latlng
  });
```

You didn't provide any position to the marker while constructing it.